# How to integrate paypal payment gateway in Grails 3.3.0

Tags: grails, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am beginner in Grails. I want to integrate paypal payment gateway in my application. I have install Grails 3 plugin but after that i don't know what to do. i want step by step process to implement paypal payment in Grails 3.3.0 web application. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need a plugin. Just refer to the REST documentation if any, then write a wrapper for it then.

Comment: exactly. The paypal API seems to be well documented: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/ . So, if you can't find a Grails plugin, it is often easy to implement a solution by yourself - you can then even publish this as a new plugin.